# Jquery 'click' not firing when icon is on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, twitter-bootstrap, click

I use `Bootstrap` and `jQuery`. I have three buttons, each with an icon in it. When I bind an `click`-event to a button, it works when I click on the button (on the edge), but not when I click on the middle of it, on the icon...

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn_change_status" id="134" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Tooltip">
      <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
   </button>
   ... 
</div>

...

$('button.btn_change_status').on('click', function(e) {
   alert(e.target.id);
   return false;
});
```

How could I bind all elements wrapped by my `btn_change_status` to the click-event?

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).on('click', 'button.btn_change_status', function(e) {...});` or even `$('button').on('click', '.btn_change_status', function(e) {...});`?

Comment: Anyway [this works good to me!](http://jsfiddle.net/KzARC/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different syntax, as per [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.btn_change_status', function(e) {
   alert(e.target.id);
   return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now it seems that the js is broken, because it does nothing... when i click on the button, nothing happens...

Answer (score 11):

Update your css with the following.  I'm assuming you don't need mouse events on your icon.

```
.icon-eye-open {

    pointer-events:none;
}
```

[MDN Information regarding pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Thanks thats the only way that works with vue.js v-on:click as I can't attach this event other way with it!! +100

Answer (score 1):

Use the following syntax for [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click','btn_change_status', function(e) {
   //write your code here
});
```

Comment: `.btn_change_status`, not `statu` ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but now it seems that the js is broken, because it does nothing... when i click on the button, nothing happens...