# HTML form not posting when clicking font awesome button text

Tags: php, html, forms, font-awesome

I am using a simple HTML to post. It works well but sometimes randomly would not post. I have deduced that it when the user clicks on the font-awesome icon. When a user clicks on the button in an area outside of the icon, the form functions correctly.

I have tried using `span` but that doesn't made a difference.

```
<form method="post" target="votar">
  <label>Subject</label>  
  <input id="subject_input" name="subject_input" type="text">
  <label>Message Body</label>             
  <textarea id="body_input" name="body_input"></textarea>
  <button id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" type="submit"><i class='fa fa-paper-plane'></i></button>
</form>
```

If it helps, I'm also using this PHP to send the form.

```
// Get data from form
    $body_input=isset($_POST['body_input'])?$_POST['body_input'].'body append':'';
    $subject_input=isset($_POST['subject_input'])?$_POST['subject_input'].'sub append':'';

// Loop sending a message for each recipient
foreach(array_column($user_ids, 'user_id') as $user_N) {
    send_msg($user_N, $body_input, $subject_input);    
}
```

Comment: do you have an if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])){}?

Comment: I don't think so, that was just the solution I came across to get the data to post. If there is no reason for it / a better way, please enlighten me. :)

Comment: Seems to behave the same (submits) no matter where I click.  https://jsfiddle.net/rboweh96/  Any chance you've added click handlers to icons somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for the fiddle. I haven't put a click handler for the icons in. Is there a way to check in the inspector? I tried changing back to just the word 'submit' and it worked fine, so definitely a font-awesome issue. Not sure why there are answers about isset. :)

Comment: Not sure about all of the browsers, but in Chrome, if you inspect an element, over on the right you can click the Event Listeners tab and it will list all the events with handlers. Expand the 'click' event and you should see all the click handlers attached

Comment: @PatrickQ Hmm. I can see one for the button and another for the wordpress top menu but nothing that refers to font-awesome. Strange.

Comment: @PatrickQ You were right, although I couldn't see anything, I added `pointer-events: none;` to the font-awesome icon and it now works. Thank you!

Comment: @redditor Glad to help. And I learned a new CSS term.  Since we know what the problem is now, voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery 'click' not firing when icon is on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085257/jquery-click-not-firing-when-icon-is-on-button)

Answer (score 0):

try

> var_dump($_POST);

and check, maybe an error here:

> target="votar",

Answer (score 0):

i don't see an isset post for your button

```
if(isset($_POST('submit_btn')){
    $body_input=isset($_POST['body_input'])?$_POST['body_input'].'body append':'';
    $subject_input=isset($_POST['subject_input'])?$_POST['subject_input'].'sub append':'';
}
```

you can add your foreach in as well where it needs to be

Comment: Even if theres none isset, the form should have been submited and php code excecuted anyways